# Entering Values To DB With PDO With Foreach Loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am entering objects from an array into a database.

I have an array called `$graphObject`

I am looping through the array like this,

```
 foreach($graphObject['tagged_places']->data as $data) {

}
```

Then I want to take each one of these values and enter them in to the `mysql DB` with `PDO`

```
 $data->id
 $data->created_time
 $data->place->id
 $data->place->location->latitude
 $data->place->location->longitude
 $data->place->name
```

I am confused on how to write this loop to enter each one of these fields `foreach` time a new field exist.

Assuming the DB connection is open and the fields in the DB are named

```
id created_time place_id latitude longitude name
```

How would I write this with PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is to build your insert in a loop and then simply execute a single insert statement.  So something like this:

```
$sql = <<<EOT
INSERT INTO table (
    `id`,
    `created_time`,
    `place_id`,
    `latitude`,
    `longitude`,
    `name`)
VALUES

EOT;

foreach($graphObject['tagged_places']->data as $data) {
    // add values into string you can remove single quotes if not needed
    // (i.e. for numeric data types)
    $values = <<<EOT
(
'{$data->id}',
'{$data->created_time}',
'{$data->place->id}',
'{$data->place->location->latitude}',
'{$data->place->location->longitude}',
'{$data->place->name}'
),
EOT;
    $sql .= $values;
}
$sql = rtrim(',', $sql);

// execute query using $sql
// assume you have properly instantiated PDO object in $pdo
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
if (false === $result) {
    // something went wrong, so log an error
    // this assumes you have not configured PDO to throw exceptions
    error_log(var_export($pdo->errorInfo(), true));
} else {
   // continue doing whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reading my whole question. Also thank you for not down voting me. I don't understand why someone did that.

Comment: @NichoDiaz You were probably down-voted, because you didn't really show code around attempts you had made for this query.

Comment: Thank you for your help, But I still get errors. `PHP Warning:  error_log() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in` Any ideas?

Comment: @NichoDiaz Sorry should have wrapped `errorInfo()` with `var_export()` to convert error array to string.  I have reflected this here.  That being said, that line of code would not get executed if there wasn't a problem with query execution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a prepared statement:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('
    INSERT INTO table
    (id, created_time, place_id, latitude, longitude, name)
    VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
');
```

Execute it on each loop

```
foreach($graphObject['tagged_places']->data as $data) {
   $stmt->execute(array(
       $data->id,
       $data->created_time,
       $data->place->id,
       $data->place->location->latitude,
       $data->place->location->longitude,
       $data->place->name
   ));
}
```